# How to get line fits from sinter.plot_error_rate to calculate logical error rate as function of physical

Tags: stim

I would like to print the gradient and intercept values for the line fits generated by sinter.plot_error_rate.

My goal is that I'm trying to find logical error rate  as a function of physical error rate for surface codes, i.e. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $p_L = \alpha (\beta p)^{\frac{d+1}{2}}$.

I have generated a bunch of threshold graphs so believe the best way to do this would be to find the line fits of $p_L$ versus $p$ for each distance on my graphs and from there find $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Using [stim](https://github.com/quantumlib/stim) and [sinter](https://pypi.org/project/sinter/) I can generate threshold graphs with line fits. For example, using the sample code from: https://pypi.org/project/sinter/ but adding line_fits argument to sinter.plot_error_rate (and setting custom xlim and ylim for the plot)

```
import stim
import sinter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Generates surface code circuit tasks using Stim's circuit generation.
def generate_example_tasks():
    for p in [0.001, 0.005, 0.01]:
        for d in [3, 5]:
            yield sinter.Task(
                circuit=stim.Circuit.generated(
                    rounds=d,
                    distance=d,
                    after_clifford_depolarization=p,
                    code_task=f'surface_code:rotated_memory_x',
                ),
                json_metadata={
                    'p': p,
                    'd': d,
                },
            )

def main():
    # Collect the samples (takes a few minutes).
    samples = sinter.collect(
        num_workers=4,
        max_shots=1_000_000,
        max_errors=1000,
        tasks=generate_example_tasks(),
        decoders=['pymatching'],
    )

    # Print samples as CSV data.
    print(sinter.CSV_HEADER)
    for sample in samples:
        print(sample.to_csv_line())

    # Render a matplotlib plot of the data.
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    sinter.plot_error_rate(
        ax=ax,
        stats=samples,
        group_func=lambda stat: f"Rotated Surface Code d={stat.json_metadata['d']}",
        x_func=lambda stat: stat.json_metadata['p'],
        line_fits = ('log','log'),
    )
    ax.loglog()
    ax.set_ylim(1e-6, 1)
    ax.set_xlim(1e-4,1e-1)
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_title('Logical Error Rate vs Physical Error Rate')
    ax.set_ylabel('Logical Error Probability (per shot)')
    ax.set_xlabel('Physical Error Rate')
    ax.legend()

    # Save to file and also open in a window.
    fig.savefig('plot.png')
    plt.show()


# NOTE: This is actually necessary! If the code inside 'main()' was at the
# module level, the multiprocessing children spawned by sinter.collect would
# also attempt to run that code.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

creates the following plot which has line fits:

[image]

How can I print out the gradient and intercept of what sinter calculated as the line fits so I can then calculate $p_L(p)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to compute the line fits for yourself to get this information.

Under the hood, sinter is using [`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html). You can use [`sinter.group_by(stats, key=group_func)`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/sinter_api.md#sinter.group_by) to split your stats up into a group for each curve, and then make the x/y points for the fitting function from those stats. Sinter has some helper methods like [`sinter.fit_line_slope`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/sinter_api.md#sinter.fit_line_slope) and [`fit_line_y_at_x`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/sinter_api.md#sinter.fit_line_y_at_x) that will give you low/best/high ranges instead of a single number, to help quantify uncertainty in the estimate.

Comment: Ok -- thank you!